# Why would a stock have a 30% spread (between Ask and Bid)?

Tags: stocks, stock-analysis, bid-ask

If I am understanding this correctly, if I wanted to buy this stock, market price is $129 ish. If I want to sell, I'll get about 30% less, $98 ish.

That seems like a huge spread.
What are typical causes of that large a spread?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the close, traders and market makers pull their bids and offers before going home.  That results in the B/A spread widening, more so for illiquid stocks.

For your stock, the quote was $129.34 x $129.37 seconds before the close.  Less than 10 seconds later, it was $128.92 x $129.62 and within one minute, it was $98.00 x $129.62 (note the time stamp on your quote).

The lesson to be learned from this?  If you're going to trade in the after hours market, make sure not to place a fat fingered trade because you WILL be filled at an outrageously inferior price and there's no recourse when it happens.

Comment: Great info. How would I determine how Illiquid MIDD is? I'd think it was reasonably liquid.Would that Volume (in screenshot) indicate liquidity?

Comment: @Clay Nichols - You can't determine liquidity by looking at one day's volume.  Your link says that  284k shares traded on Friday.  Was this a normal trading day?  Though we know it now, if this snapshot had been from weeks or months ago, was it a holiday half day or a full day of trading?  Was there special news that increased volume? ... Actual facts?  MIDD averaged about 618k shares a day over the past year, far short of the 8.67 million shares it traded in May when it announced  disappointing earnings. Yes, it's liquid.

Answer (score 1):

This is not very common during market hours. Such a spread can only be observed during the pre- and post-market sessions because of pending after market hour orders and  Good 'Til Canceled orders.

Comment: Spreads like that do happen during normal hours but to equities that are extremely illiquid.

Comment: Hence the phrase: "not very common during market hours"